# Cannot create a RegExp project in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

In js, I use regular expression validation to check if my input string matches with a special character as shown below or not. So I use test() method of RegExp object.

BUT, I always get an exception error said that:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   /[^@/[]<>?:;,*=|+"]*/: Nothing to repeat

Special character that I want to check in the input string:

> ^ @ / [ ] < > ? : ; ,
>   *
>   = |
>   + "

```js
var str = "My Test String";
var re = new RegExp('[^@/\[\]\&lt;\&gt;\?:;,*=|\+\&quot;]*');
var result = re.test(str);

alert(result);
```

Am I doing something wrong in the code?

Comment: Why did you add entities to the *character class* that only matches a single char from the set? The error is well-known, inside constructor notation you need to use double backslashes to escape special chars. Also, `^` in the beginning of a character class created a *negated* character class, so your regex matches anything other than `@`, `/`, `[` and then followed with a sequence of patterns. Did you intend to use `var re = /[@^<>\/[\]?:;,*=|+"]|&(?:quot|[gl]t);/`?

Comment: Or is `re = /[@^\/[\]<>?:;,*=|+"]/` enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is well-known, inside constructor notation you need to use double backslashes to escape special chars. The `|+` causes the issue here, since the character class ends prematurely with the `\]`, and the rest is a *sequence* of patterns outside a character class.

Regarding

> Special character that I want to check in the input string:
>
> `^ @ / [ ] < > ? : ; , * = | + "`

You just may use a [`/[@^\/[\]<>?:;,*=|+"]/`](https://regex101.com/r/tWYYuO/1) regex.

```js
var str = "My Test String";
var re = /[@^\/[\]<>?:;,*=|+"]/;
var result = re.test(str);
console.log(result ? "Special chars found!" : "No special chars found!");
```

Adding entities like `&gt;` into the character class that only matches a single char from the set will make the regex match `g`, `t` and `&` as separate chars. 
`^` in the beginning of a character class created a negated character class, so your regex matches anything other than `@`, `/`, `[` and then followed with a sequence of patterns.

If you need to incluse entities, add them as an alternative:

```
var re = /[@^<>\/[\]?:;,*=|+"]|&(?:quot|[gl]t);/
```